# R Shiny dynamic CSS within checkboxGroupButtons

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets

I am unable to dynamically alter the `status` of `checkboxGroupButtons`. Please see the following, where the `choices` alter dynamically, but the status only renders as the final variable within the `for` loop (in this case 3 is printed repeatedly, as opposed to 1,2,3).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

example = cbind(c("a", "b", "c"), c(1, 2, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("example_output"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$example_output = renderUI({
    example_output = c()
    for (i in 1:nrow(example)) {
      example_output[[i]] = tagList()
      example_output[[i]] = checkboxGroupButtons(paste0("id_", i), choices = {
        print(example[i, 1])
        example[i, 1]
      },
      status = {
        print(i)
        example[i, 2]
      })
    }
    example_output
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I alter the `status` dynamically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

example = cbind(c("a", "b", "c"), c(1, 2, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("example_output"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$example_output = renderUI({    
    tagList(
      lapply(1:nrow(example), function(i){
        checkboxGroupButtons(paste0("id_", i), choices = {
          print(example[i, 1])
          example[i, 1]
        },
        status = {
          print(i)
          example[i, 2]
        })
      })
    )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```